# React multiple children seem to be sharing the component handler function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a relatively simple Bootstrap card layout in React with multiple cards, each of which has a toggle switch on it. However, whichever toggle switch is pressed it's always the handler function for the first card that is called (and hence the first toggle changes state). I can't understand why they aren't calling their own functions.

The structure I have is the card-deck has multiple card children, each of which has a toggle switch child, e.g. card deck -> card -> toggle

**Card deck**

```
class CardDeck extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    data: [
      {title: 'Cat 1'},
      {title: 'Cat 2'},
      {title: 'Cat 3'}
    ]
  }
}

render() {
  return (
    <div class="card-deck">
    {this.state.data.map((item, index) =>
          <Card
            key={index}
            title={item.title}
            index={index}
            id={index}
          />
         )}
    </div>
  );
}

}
```

**Card**

```
class Card extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    checked: false,
  }
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

handleChange() {
  this.setState({
    checked: !this.state.checked,
  });
}

render() {
  return (
      <div class="card" key={this.props.index}>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">{this.props.title}</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
          <Toggle checkStatus={this.state.checked} onChange={this.handleChange} key={this.props.index} />
        </div>
      </div>

  );
}

}
```

**Toggle**

```
class Toggle extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitches" onChange={this.props.onChange} checked={this.props.checkStatus} />
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitches">Label</label>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I do not see a problem with this code. Can you put that in a sandbox and reproduce it?

Comment: The  syntax error I can see is in Card component .  handleChange --> handleChange()

handleChange {
  this.setState({
    checked: !this.state.checked,
  });
}

also <div class=card-"footer">
          <Toggle checkStatus={this.state.checked} onChange={this.handleChange} key={this.props.index} />
        </div>

class = "card-footer" . I am not sure if this copy paste error or not?

Comment: I'm trying to get it working in a sandbox but failing so far.

Comment: They were all copy/paste errors but thank you. I've edited to fix those.

Comment: So I got it working in the sandbox and couldn't reproduce the issue. On further investigation it seems like the issue lies in the fact that I'm actually using a bootstrap toggle class "custom-control-input". When I remove this the issue goes away. Any ideas? I may create a new question that's more specific...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple workaround is to pass an id `prop` to `toggle component` because each checkbox control id should be unique but in your case, you are using the same id attribute value for all the three checkboxes so in other to differentiate the checkboxes I passed an id `prop` to `toggle component` and append to the id attribute value of each checkbox so as to make them unique.

**Toggle Component**

```
class Toggle extends React.Component {
  render () {
    console.log(this.props.id)
    return (
      <div className='custom-control custom-switch'>
        <input
          type='checkbox'
          className='custom-control-input'
          id={`customSwitches${this.props.id}`}
          onChange={this.props.onChange}
          checked={this.props.checkStatus}
        />
        <label
          className='custom-control-label'
          htmlFor={`customSwitches${this.props.id}`}
        >
          Label
        </label>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**Card component**

```
class Card extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      checked: false
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange () {
    this.setState({
      checked: !this.state.checked
    })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className='card' key={this.props.index}>
        <div className='card-body'>
          <h5 className='card-title'>{this.props.title}</h5>
          <p className='card-text'>Text</p>
        </div>
        <div className='card-footer'>
          <Toggle
            checkStatus={this.state.checked}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            key={this.props.index}
            id={this.props.index}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! You're exactly right. Because I had the same id for each of the controls it was, I presume, just linking back to the first control. I've concatenated the index onto the previous id and it works.